# Root Finding Algorithm of a Positive and Negative root

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, find

[image]

Hi, I have to devise an algorithm for this. I've looked into bisection, newton and it seems like bisection method is correct but it requires a algorithm to go off. e.g. x^3 + x - 2 = 0. Is there anyway to have a generalised algorithm for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary search will find (one of the) roots.

What they're suggesting is assuming the function is linear between `(a, f(a))` and `(b, f(b))`, and picking the point where a straight line between those points crosses the x axis.  i.e. assume

```
f(x) = m * x + b
```

This will probably converge faster than simple binary search of `new_x = (a+b)/2`.

Comment: Hello, but don't we need to give an algorithm to find the root instead of assuming an equation? Sorry i'm really confused with this

Comment: @JacksonCollins: no, you iterate until you've narrowed the range down to some threshold.  It's a successive-iteration method that makes a more accurate guess every iteration.  All you need is a formula for making a next guess, and a way to decide when to stop.  In this case, you evaluate `f(new_x)`, and see whether it has opposite sign to `f(a)` or `f(b)`.   That's your new range.

Comment: @PeterCordes If you try this on nearly any function, you will find that only one endpoint will ever change. Because of this, your suggested termination criterion will usually fail and the algorithm will run an infinite loop. Also, this is known as the false position (or regula falsi) method. It's known to be fairly unreliable, often giving convergence slower than the bisection method, on the side it does converge.